# How to create a Views relationship using the Address Field module?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I am trying to create a view to filter content types assigned to a specific country (set using [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module), determined by the current node's title.

My address field is not being listed under relationships in views.

How am I able to set contextual filters by a nodes country? Is this currently possible, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The country should be filtered by the current node's title

The better approach is to create Taxonomy Terms, so you can tag your nodes.

In `admin/structure/taxonomy` Add a vocabulary called Countries.

Then add a term reference field to your content type and select countries as your vocabulary, and use auto complete widget.

So all you have to is type the country name here and it will tag your node with that name.

In views, for contextual filter add Has taxonomy term ID

[image]

**PS:** You could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to auto tag your nodes based on the Country field value.

Comment: I am able to follow the steps you have above, however I do not wish to expose this option to users. The country should be filtered by the current node's title (Which will be the name of a country).

My view is of the type "Content".

Are you able to see Address Field fields (such as country) under the relationships tab?

Once again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `Are you able to see Address Field fields (such as country) under the relationships tab?` Nope, nothing with country shows up here. Furthermore, when I try to contextual filter by country nothing shows up, seems to me that this module is buggy.

Comment: Yep, that is what I think aswell. I will try and get in touch with the developers of the module and see if I can find a solution.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I discovered something, the contextual filter works with two character country code. So instead of United States, you put US

Comment: @BokBok re-updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: Thank you!

The above answer sounds like it will work perfectly.

I really appreciate all your help!